# How to style a class inside another class in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I have two Rows sharing the same class name in the same page. I want to set the second row's background color to a different color. 
So I tried to wrap the content of the second row with a class to style it.
This is the code:

This is the firs grid:

```
<Row className="show-grid">
          <Col xs={12} md={6}>
           //Some content
          </Col>
          <Col xs={0} md={1}>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={12} md={5}>
            // some content
          </Col>
        </Row>
```

Now this is the second grid that I want to change it's background color:

```
<Row className="show-grid">
        <div className="second-grid">

          <Col xs={12} md={6}>
            // content
          </Col>
          <Col xs={0} md={1}>
          </Col>

          <Col xs={12} md={5}>
           // content
          </Col>

          </div>
        </Row>
        {/*
        **********End of section two
        */}
```

I tried use this css but it's not changing any thing:

```
.show-grid .second-grid {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: What's the actual markup produced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a js object like this :

```
/* stuff */
render(){
    var style = {backgroundColor:"#ffffff"};
    return(
        <Row className="show-grid" style={stye}>
        </Row>
    )
}
```

Or you can try to use a css like this :

```
.show-grid>.second-grid {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: ah where was my brain! I totally forgot to use an object, Thank you :)